# How can I create a 3-column nested CSS Grid layout?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am try to achieve a 3-column layout like this:

```
    ---------------------------------------------
    |Header (100%)                              |
    |-------------------------------------------|
    |Images (50%)        |Description (50%)     |
    |--------------------|----------------------|
    |Image 1  |  Image 2 |   Description        |
    |         |----------|                      |
    |         |  Image 3 |                      |
    |         |          |                      |
    |         |          |                      |
    |         |          |                      |
    ---------------------------------------------
```

My problem is that Image 1 is quite long (an image of a one-pager website).  Image 2 and Image 3 are pushed very far away from each other since the row of Image 3 only starts after the lengthy Image 1 ends. I want Image 2 and Image 3 (quite low height) to stack up on each other.

```css
.design-portfolio {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
.sintra {
    grid-row: 1;
}
.joia {
    grid-row: 2;
}
.guitar {
    grid-row: 3;
}
.sintra, .joia, .guitar {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}
.sintra h3, .joia h3, .guitar h3 {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 1;
}
.images {
        grid-column: 1;
        max-height: auto;
        grid-row: 2/3;
        display: grid;
        justify-items: center; 
        grid-template-columns: minmax(20%, 1fr) 1fr;
        grid-gap: 5px;
}
.image1 {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row:1/2;
    max-height: auto;
    max-width: 90%; 
    object-fit: contain;
}
.image2 {
    grid-column: 2;
    max-width: 90%; 
    object-fit: contain;
}
.image3 {
    grid-column: 2;
    max-width: 90%; 
    object-fit: contain;
}
.description, .description,  .description {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2/3;
    width: 75%;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="design-portfolio">
    <article class="sintra">
       <h3>We spot Sintra - Boulder Festival Event</h3>

       <div class="images">
             <img class="image1" src="images/sintra.svg" alt="Sintra Subsite">
             <img class="image2" src="images/sintra2.svg" alt="Sintra Subsite">
             <img class="image3" src="images/sintra3.svg" alt="Sintra Website">
       </div>

       <div class="description">
              <h4>Challenge</h4>
              <p>The Challenge was to create a website (desktop/mobile) for an event.</p>
              <h4>Activities</h4>
              p>UX Research, User Flow, Site Maps, Wireframing (Adobe XD), Prototyping (Adobe XD)</p>
        </div>
     </article>
    <article class="joia">
    </article>
    <article class="guitar">
    </article>
</div>
```

Comment: looks like .description is the one stretching the whole row here, try adding `margin-bottom:auto` to `.image` so it doesn't stretch all the way down the row where it stands. or increase .description row spanning .

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I visualize to solve your problem is to think of the grid as a 3x4 table.

You will wonder why?

Well, having a table of three rows and four columns presents the following structure:

```
+===============+=======+=======+=======+
| Row 1 / Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 4 |
+===============+=======+=======+=======+
| Row 2         |       |       |       |
+---------------+-------+-------+-------+
| Row 3         |       |       |       |
+---------------+-------+-------+-------+
```

That generates the following css-grid code:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: auto repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
```

Seen this way, the solution is quite simple, you just need to combine the columns/rows you need, in this case:

```
+========+========+========+========+
|               Header              |
+========+========+========+========+
|        |        |        |        |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|        |        |        |        |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

That can be achieved the following css-grid code:

```css
.header-container {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 5;
}
```

Next:

```
+=========+=========+=========+=========+
|                 Header                |
+=========+=========+=========+=========+
|         |         |         |         |
+ Image 1 +---------+---------+---------+
|         |         |         |         |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

That can be achieved the following css-grid code:

```css
.image1-container {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 4 / 2;
}
```

Next:

```
+=========+=========+=========+=========+
|                 Header                |
+=========+=========+=========+=========+
|         | Image 2 |         |         |
+ Image 1 +---------+---------+---------+
|         | Image 3 |         |         |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

That can be achieved the following css-grid code:

```css
.image2-container {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
}

.image3-container {
  grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 3;
}
```

Finally, we get:

```
+=========+=========+=========+=========+
|                 Header                |
+=========+=========+=========+=========+
|         | Image 2 |                   |
+ Image 1 +---------+    Description    +
|         | Image 3 |                   |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

That can be achieved the following css-grid code:

```css
.description-container {
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 4 / 5;
}
```

Getting, for example:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr) );
  grid-template-rows: auto repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container img {
  object-fit: cover;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.header-container {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 5;
}

.image1-container {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 4 / 2;
}

.image2-container {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
}

.image3-container {
  grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 3;
}

.description-container {
  align-self: start;
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 4 / 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header-container">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="image1-container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/350/500" alt="Lorem picsum">
  </div>
  <div class="image2-container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Lorem picsum">
  </div>
  <div class="image3-container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/250" alt="Lorem picsum">
  </div>
  <div class="description-container">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h2>
    <p>Pellentesque interdum, nisl vitae facilisis ultrices, ipsum augue malesuada purus, id fermentum sem mauris vel justo. Nulla facilisi. Nam et vehicula enim. In vulputate finibus lorem, quis tincidunt odio eleifend vitae. Praesent fringilla molestie molestie. Curabitur eget placerat eros, vel sodales odio. Nam rutrum mauris ipsum, a pretium urna laoreet consequat. Suspendisse tincidunt quam sit amet odio efficitur, nec imperdiet ligula dictum. Proin at semper augue. Proin blandit ac quam at pharetra. Sed dignissim erat est, in blandit felis egestas non. Ut orci dolor, sodales et massa in, commodo imperdiet lacus. Nam non tortor risus. Proin enim leo, tempor id facilisis id, aliquet sit amet tortor. Duis eleifend nibh quis magna cursus ornare.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque interdum, nisl vitae facilisis ultrices, ipsum augue malesuada purus, id fermentum sem mauris vel justo. Nulla facilisi. Nam et vehicula enim. In vulputate finibus lorem, quis tincidunt odio eleifend vitae. Praesent fringilla molestie molestie. Curabitur eget placerat eros, vel sodales odio. Nam rutrum mauris ipsum, a pretium urna laoreet consequat. Suspendisse tincidunt quam sit amet odio efficitur, nec imperdiet ligula dictum. Proin at semper augue. Proin blandit ac quam at pharetra. Sed dignissim erat est, in blandit felis egestas non. Ut orci dolor, sodales et massa in, commodo imperdiet lacus. Nam non tortor risus. Proin enim leo, tempor id facilisis id, aliquet sit amet tortor. Duis eleifend nibh quis magna cursus ornare.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque interdum, nisl vitae facilisis ultrices, ipsum augue malesuada purus, id fermentum sem mauris vel justo. Nulla facilisi. Nam et vehicula enim. In vulputate finibus lorem, quis tincidunt odio eleifend vitae. Praesent fringilla molestie molestie. Curabitur eget placerat eros, vel sodales odio. Nam rutrum mauris ipsum, a pretium urna laoreet consequat. Suspendisse tincidunt quam sit amet odio efficitur, nec imperdiet ligula dictum. Proin at semper augue. Proin blandit ac quam at pharetra. Sed dignissim erat est, in blandit felis egestas non. Ut orci dolor, sodales et massa in, commodo imperdiet lacus. Nam non tortor risus. Proin enim leo, tempor id facilisis id, aliquet sit amet tortor. Duis eleifend nibh quis magna cursus ornare.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque interdum, nisl vitae facilisis ultrices, ipsum augue malesuada purus, id fermentum sem mauris vel justo. Nulla facilisi. Nam et vehicula enim. In vulputate finibus lorem, quis tincidunt odio eleifend vitae. Praesent fringilla molestie molestie. Curabitur eget placerat eros, vel sodales odio. Nam rutrum mauris ipsum, a pretium urna laoreet consequat. Suspendisse tincidunt quam sit amet odio efficitur, nec imperdiet ligula dictum. Proin at semper augue. Proin blandit ac quam at pharetra. Sed dignissim erat est, in blandit felis egestas non. Ut orci dolor, sodales et massa in, commodo imperdiet lacus. Nam non tortor risus. Proin enim leo, tempor id facilisis id, aliquet sit amet tortor. Duis eleifend nibh quis magna cursus ornare.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```